# Is this differential form $\overline{\partial}$ exact?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-geometry

1. Let $(z,w)$ be ccordinates on $\mathbb C^2$. It is not difficult to show that $1$ - form
   $$\omega:=\dfrac{\overline{zw} \cdot\overline{dw}-\overline{w}^2\cdot\overline{dz}}{(|z|^2+|w|^2)^3}$$

is $\overline{\partial}$ closed on $\mathbb C^2\backslash0$.

2. Is it true that it is exact?
3. Can I find explicitly smooth function $f$, such that $\omega = \overline{\partial}f$?

Comment: Problem is I need $z,w$  in denominator of $f$, but it is not defined on $\mathbb C^2\backslash 0$. Also I don't know very much about the first cohomology of structure sheaf on $\mathbb C^2\backslash 0$.

Comment: You might want to add that to the question. Users like it when there's evidence you've made an effort yourself, and it helps understand what level to pitch an answer.

Comment: I don't believe  that $\omega$ is closed. If you write down your calculations users will be able to check whether I or you made a mistake.